# Getting 'data' value from a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code:

```
let blob = repo.getBlob(sha, function(){
    console.log("===== BLOB =====");
    console.log(blob);
});
```

Which outputs the following Promise:
[image]

The only information I need from this Promise is the 'data' line:
[image]

What do I need to print in order to get just that value?

Comment: You're *probably* supposed to do `repo.getBlob(sha).then(data => ...)`…?!

Comment: It's unlikely that you can use `blob.data` the way @brae commented, since blob will not have that data at the time of reaching the console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `repo.getBlob(sha)` returns a promise, then you can do:

```
repo.getBlob(sha).then(data=> console.log(data))
```

Or you can try

```
repo.getBlob(sha, function(err, data){
    console.log("===== BLOB =====");
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do like this:

```
let blob = repo.getBlob(sha, function (error, data) {
    console.log("===== BLOB =====");
    console.log(data);
});
```

Or you can try this:

```
repo.getBlob(sha).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using `nodegit` library.

So according to the [nodegit API documentation](http://www.nodegit.org/api/repository/#getBlob) you have to call `getBlob` method this way:

```
repository.getBlob(String).then(function(blob) {
  // Use blob
});
```

Good luck!